# HTML5 Drag and Drop (DnD): changing cursor

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

While dragging an element over the browser client area in HTML5, how can I change the cursor to any cursor that I want?

So far, I've only been able to display the default cursor while dragging (except for the none cursor wherever dropping is not supported).

I'm not talking about any of the following:

- using `event.dataTransfer.setDragImage()` to display an image besides the cursor
- using `event.dataTransfer.dropEffect` to display a copy or a link symbol besides the cursor, or to change the cursor to the none symbol
- in Firefox, using `event.dataTransfer.mozCursor`, since that can only perform the default system behavior, or display the arrow cursor, neither of which helps (besides, I want cross browser support, though I'm primarily targeting Chrome)

I've tried many other tricks, including using CSS `:hover` and `:focus`, and many JavaSscript tricks, all to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to change the cursor when using html 5 drag & drop (instead of just normal mouse moves).  I think that it is for security, to ensure that the web page doesn't try to trick a user into thinking that dropping in an area will behave other than expected.  I just switched to using normal mouse moves instead of drag and drop.

Comment: I have the same problem. I agree with you. We may need to switch back to mousedown/mousemove events instead of H5 Dnd

Comment: I think you need to target the "droppable". Something like `document.querySelector('.droppable').style.cursor = 'whatever'`

Comment: Why dont you try the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27811047/3513687

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom cursor with drag and drop an HTML element without libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447210/custom-cursor-with-drag-and-drop-an-html-element-without-libraries)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447210/custom-cursor-with-drag-and-drop-an-html-element-without-libraries/44611187

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS only solution!

```
element:hover:active {
cursor: type;
}
```

Just put the element selector where element is and specify a cursor. This is a bit of a hack, because it does not detect dragging, only hover and click at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it with css

```
#buttonId:hover {
    cursor: value;
}
```

you can find multiple cursor values here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use CSS as followed:

```
#buttonID:hover:active {
cursor: *cursor-type*;
}
```

There are several cursor types you can use, which are:

*help*; - will display the default cursor with a little question mark on the side

*wait*; - will display the default loading cursor animation of your OS

*crosshair*; - will give you a crosshair cursor

*not-allowed*; - will display a  icon for your cursor

*zoom-in*; - will display a magnifier with a plus inside

*grab*; - will display a hand, this one will suit your needs the best I think.

These are all **cursor:** properties I know of. You might find some of the useful.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to change your cursor while dragging an element?

```
$('YourElement').draggable({
     cursor: "crosshair"
});
```

see http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cursor for more info

Answer (score -1):

Hi Try this out by Making an element draggable requires adding the given code

```
<script>
function dragstart_handler(ev) {
// Add the target element's id to the data transfer object
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
// Get the element by id
const element = document.getElementById("p1");
// Add the ondragstart event listener
element.addEventListener("dragstart", dragstart_handler);
});
</script>

<p id="p1" draggable="true">This element is draggable.</p>
```

Comment: How does that change the mouse cursor?