# Changing cursor while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag, mouse-cursor

Is it possible to change the cursor while dragging?

I have been searching and trying to do it for a while now. I want to change the 'not-allowed' cursor which shows up while you drag an object to another cursor.

I tried creating an event and assigning it to the image I wanted to drag:-

```
<img id="drag1" class="drag" src="http://www.surfixe.com/img/tick2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
```

JavaScript:-

```
function drag(ev) {
    $('#drag1').css('cursor', 'pointer');
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/wpcbM/2/)

Edit: Note: My little project is supposed to be html-5 `drag and drop`, so I need to be able to change the cursor while dragging a div with html-5 `drag` attribute

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find any solution? Here is a duplicate link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930811/html5-drag-and-drop-dnd-changing-cursor

Answer (score 2):

The 'not-allowed' cursor simply showed that there´s been no draggable at all.
You have to bind your img with `.draggable()` method http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/
it has it´s own option for a specific cursor to be used while dragging.

you can use it as easy like

```
$( "#drag1" ).draggable({ cursor: "pointer" });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wpcbM/3/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but can u link me to the jquery UI?

Comment: ah okay I missed you dont use jqueryUI, jquery itself doesnt provide draggable afaik  but you can easily build it yourself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569095/draggable-div-without-jquery-ui

Comment: BTW doesn't work on "over" and "out" methods (events where you would like to manipulate them dynamically)

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is possible. You should change the cursor of item that you are dragging (not the destination one).

Comment: He is already applying the styles to the dragged element. And no, with native HTML5 drag and drop doesn't working just by changing the cursor of the dragged element either.

Comment: yes you are right, authro already applied the css on draggable, I miss it. It have worked for me with jquery ui draggable "helper": I'have applied  "nodrop" cursor on it when mouse was over the forbidden area. It seems helper in jquery draggable organized not trivial way.

Comment: It is possible that helper in jquery ui draggable is regular element with absolute positioning binded to mousemove. so that is why it is work for me.