# HTML5 Drag & Drop change cursor while dragging (don't use UI)

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I want to change the `cursor` when dragging, so I try this way:

```js
function drag (event) {

    localStorage.setItem("no", $(event.target).data("no"));

    $("html").css("cursor", "move");

}
```

```html
<tr draggable="true" class="memo_item move" id="memo_<?php echo $memo->memo_no?>" ondragstart="drag(event, this);" data-no="<?php echo $memo->memo_no?>"></tr>
```

but it doesn't work.

And I can't use `JQueryUi`.

How can I change cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply implement this kind of event setup in your code...

```
$('<some element here>').on('dragstart', function() {
  $(this).css("cursor", "move");
});
```

However, this will permanently change the cursor on the element, to toggle this cursor change add

```
$('<some element here>').on('dragend', function() {
  $(this).css("cursor", "default"); // or whatever pointer you want to revert to
});
```

Comment: Above code just use jQuery to register H5 drag event. No jQuery UI. @NathanHornby By thy way, it seems we cannot just drag cursor.

Comment: My mistake. Their presence in the jQuery UI docs, but not in the jQuery docs led me to believe otherwise - hadn't realised they were native events as part of the DragEvent interface https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent

Comment: This does not change the cursor. I am not aware of a way to do this since HTML5 drag locks the pointer to `default`.

Comment: I am not sure of the intent here. But you don't need js to change a cursor on hover. There is nothing locking the cursor to `default`. https://jsfiddle.net/8nh6ekbp/

Comment: fiddle by Rafael ( jsfiddle.net/8nh6ekbp ) doesn't work. cursor is indeed locked